# Modify php file and variable in it

Tags: php

I have email.php file with example code:

```
<?php
$emailsubject = 'Test subject'; 
$html='<html>example</html>';
?>
```

In another file editor.php I'm making form with input fields where i will edit $html variable from email.php file.

So after posting I will have this

```
$_POST['html'] = '<html>edited example</html>';
```

Now my plan is to overwrite email.php and make it be:

```
<?php
$emailsubject = 'Test subject'; 
$html='<html>edited example</html>';
?>
```

So can i use something like this:

```
$old = file_get_contents('email.php');
$new = str_replace ('<html>example</html>'/* or $html if i include email.php file */ , $_POST['html'] , $old)
file_put_contents('email.php', $new);
```

Comment: your idea to dynamically change the source code of your script isn't a really good idea

Comment: you are trying to change the html code, how can  we change the code, it's not a good thing

Comment: basicly yes. I have some php files with email contents. And now my plan is to make somehow editor for them and change content of this php files. If is not a good idea is there better approach editing php files and changing content and value of the variables in them or its very bad practice?

Comment: change `$html='<html>example</html>';` to `$html= getHtml();`: `getHtml()` can retrive the contents somewhere (a database, a file, ...), then your `editor.php` can change that.

Comment: @Federkun I understand. You recommend me to exclude value of variable into db ,for example, so basicaly I will not need to overwrite file but instead just to update value in db?

Comment: yeah. the easy way: `$html=file_get_contents('contents.html');` and `file_put_contents('contents.html', $_POST['html']);`.